# When textFieldDidEndEditing gets called, the app freezes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, delegates, uitextfield

I have a custom `UITableView` with `UITextFields` inside. In `cellForRow...` I made the `textFields` delegate to self. (In my main VC class.) The way I get the text from the `textField` is at `textFieldDidEndEditing`, and I add it to a `mutableArray`.

I then have different cell ids that get added when a button gets selected:

```
- (IBAction)addRow:(id)sender
{
    NSInteger row = [self.rowArray cound];
    [self.rowArray insertObject:@"anotherCell" atIndex:row];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSindexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0];
    [self.myTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

(There is a `textField` in that `cellID` and I set the `delegate` to self.)

In `textFieldDidEndEditing`, I made an `NSLog` of `textField.text`, and when that method gets called from a `textField` that was there initially, it works as expected.

But when `textFieldDidEndEditing` gets called from the `textField` that's in the cell of `anotherCell` (the added cell), then the whole simulator freezes.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellID = [self.rowArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    customCell *cell = [tableView dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier:cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.name.delegate = self; // From cell that is initially there
    cell.phoneNumber.delegate = self; // From the added cell

    return cell;
}
```

(If this is confusing, or if you need more code, just let me know in the comments. Thanks)

**Edit**

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField.tag <= 9)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", textField.text); // This works
    }

    UIView *superview = textField.superview;
    while (![superview isMemberOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
        superview = superview.superview;
    }
    CustomCellClass *cell = (CustomCellClass *)superview;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.myTableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    if (textField.tag >= 12)
    {
        if ([self.inputArray count] > indexPath.row) // So I won't get the error message of [__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds for empty array'
        {
            for (NSUInteger i = [self.inputArray count]; i < indexPath.row; i++) {
                [self.inputArray insertObject:@"" atIndex:i];
                NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)i);
            }
        }

        NSLog(@"%@", self.inputArray);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger with a breakpoint on that delegate callback to see how far it's getting into it if at all before the app freezes?

Comment: What you're doing is not the normal way to use a table view. You should only have one cell identifier for each cell type. So, if you only have one dynamic prototype, you should only have one identifier. Also, if the problem occurs when textFieldDidEndEditing is called, then you need to show what code you have in that method.

Comment: Just up[dated my question with the method. Also, I do have more than 1 cell id

Comment: Updated the question and added the method of `textFieldDidEndEditing`. Also, I have more than 1 cell type.

Comment: What do you mean by "freezes"? Does the table view no longer scroll? When this happens, does the code reach the if (textField.tag >= 12) clause? Is so, does the log of self.inputArray print out?

Comment: I cannot do anything in the simulator. (ex. If I try selected a button, nothing will happen.) Made an NSLog, and it doesn't even reach the if statement of `textField.tag >= 12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is stuck in an infinite loop here:

```
while (![superview isMemberOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
    superview = superview.superview;
}
```

because `isMemberOfClass` will return true only if the superview class is `UITableViewCell`, but NOT if it is a *subclass* of `UITableViewCell`.  If you change `isMemberOfClass` to `isKindOfClass`, it should work.  Check the Apple docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isKindOfClass:).

Comment: Thanks. By the way, when getting the superview of the textField, is there a difference between what you posted and this: CGPoint pointInTable = [textFIeld convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:_self.myTableView];    

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.myTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:pointInTable];

Comment: @Edison I don't think one solution has any particular advantage over the other.  Personally I feel uncomfortable about recursing up the view hierarchy to find a reference to the cell, so I prefer the other solution, but that's just my personal preference.